# Unable set focus on cursor

Tags: google-chrome, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a very strange behavior only when using Google Chrome.

When I open my website (i am using primefaces)  at the first time I am unable set focus on cursor.

The “workaround” will be to open another tab and suddenly I get the control back on the cursor.

Any I idea why this happen and how can I resolve it ?

(only with Chrome).

Thanks

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <p:layout fullPage="true" >
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="50" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false">
            <h:form>
                <ui:include src="menu_header.xhtml"/>
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">
            <h:form id="mainForm" prependId="false">

            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="30" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false" style="overflow:hidden">
            <div id="footer" class="ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
                <h:outputText value="#{navMenuBean.footer}" styleClass="defualtTextSize"/>
            </div>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</ui:define>
```

Comment: Ok so I finally found the root cause for this problem with Chrome.

Apparently when I set the layout full page attribute to true then only at the first time I will not be able to get cursor focus.

“<p:layout fullPage="true" >”

Any idea why is that ?

Thanks

Comment: Found a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557106/jsf-primefaces-menubar-dropdown-submenu-disapearing-after-hover-in-playout